# Synchronize the execution in NodeJS code

Tags: node.js, synchronization, mongojs

I'm trying to do the following:

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var db = mongojs("myplaylist", ["songs"])

data = [{}, {}, {}, .... ]     /*Array of objects*/

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     console.log(data);
     db.songs.save(data[i], function(err, data[i]){
          if(error) throw error;
          console.log(data[i]);
     });
}
```

`

In the above snippet, iteration gets over by displaying all the items in data array without saving a single record in database.

Please help me in this particular problem.

Comment: update your save code in question

Comment: @kgangadhar I've modified the snippet. Please check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `save` is an  asynchronous function you need to use `callbacks`, `promise` or `async/await`. Here's an example of how you can handle this with promise:

```
var mongojs = require("mongojs");
var db = mongojs("myplaylist", ["songs"])

data = [{}, {}, {}, .... ]     /*Array of objects*/

var data_arr = [];
data.forEach(element => {
    data_arr.push(db.songs.save(element));
});

Promise.all(data_arr).then(response =>{
    console.log(response) //contains response array of each save call
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me...Thanks a lot..Really appreciate your help :)